# Adding key mapping to the vim mode of the Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I've embedded the ace editor into my website and I would like to map Cmd+e to the right movement key in the insertion mode of the vim mode, so I added:

```
  ace.config.loadModule("ace/keybinding/vim", function() {
      Vim = require("ace/keyboard/vim").Vim
      Vim.map("j", "gj", "normal")
      Vim.map("k", "gk", "normal")
      Vim.map("<C-e>", "<Right>", "insert")
});
```

While the key mapping for `j` and `k` do work, the one for Cmd+e does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vim `C-` means Control key, the Command key is `D-` but vim mode in ace doesn't support it.

However in insert mode it is possible to use ace command instead of vim mode command by calling

```
editor.commands.bindKey("Cmd-j", "gotoright")
```